Why does subdivided cube frame look messed up?
I add a cube, duplicate it and scale the second down by 0.8.  I then extrude all the faces of the second cube out by 1.  Then I subtract the second from the first.  All looks good until I subdivide.  How come?  what is a better workflow?



I would recommend looking into some tutorials on Subdivision Surface modeling. It's an extremely layered topic within 3D Graphics.  TL;DR you have to add support loops on sharp corners you want to keep sharp.

Boolean based modelling is largely incompatible with subdivision surface modelling

At least right off the bat, yes. You can get there but it won't work right away. Even in the best case scenarios this workflow will take a fair bit of work.

Ian McGlasham has some videos about Subdivision Surface modelling in his channel. This one is about the cube.
